# Resources to learn SuiteCRM?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am a developer who has no experience working with CRM systems. I want to build a simple system using SuiteCRM. But I can't find a single tutorial for SuiteCRM in the internet. Believe me I spent several days searching for tutorials but I couldn't find. The official [Userguides](https://suitecrm.com/wiki/index.php/Userguides) documentation is absolutely useless for development purposes. I found this book [SuiteCRM For Developers](https://leanpub.com/suitecrmfordevelopers) but it is not suitable for a beginner. And it doesn't cover most of the basic stuff. Please suggest me a good tutorial(document/video) which covers topics such as creating custom entities(operations with custom entities), workflows and REST api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Welcome to world of CRM !!

First learn the flow of modules which are available in CRM and then go ahead with the development part. So I will suggest you to learn SugarCRM first. As coding standards and execution flow of SuiteCRM and SugarCRM is same.

> - Download [SugarCRM CE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sugarcrm/files/)
> - Install the CRM in your    machine as described [here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/CE/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/)
> - Once installed play with modules. [Getting_Started SugarCRM](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/CE/Application_Guide/Getting_Started/)
> - Take an overview on admin features of SugarCRM as described in detail [here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/)
> - Try to create new modules as per described [here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Studio_and_Module_Builder/Creating_a_Custom_Module_With_Module_Builder/)

Comment: Thank you. Can I try these things with SuiteCRM installation. Because I already setup a server for that

Comment: Yes. You can do it

Answer (score 9):

If you're new to CRM world, as I was a couple of years ago, Id suggest doing the following:

1. Get a copy of SugarCRM for Dummies.  It gives you an overview of the built in modules and functions of SugarCRM.
2. Watch how-to videos on SugarCRM for more in-depth details on particular modules.
3. Get a copy of SuiteCRM for Developers by Jim Mackin.  This was a game changer for me.  it's straight forward but breaks down the essentials of SuiteCRM.

From there, it's all about googling and practice.  The more you play with the code, the more it starts making sense.

Answer (score 4):

I've been digging into some SUiteCRM work also lately, and the SugarCRM info is very helpful. The SuiteCRM forums have been getting some more traction lately.

https://suitecrm.com/forum/developer-help/10338-how-to-create-a-custom-module-from-scratch

I am also going to buy this book, looks like a great resource! https://leanpub.com/suitecrmfordevelopers

Answer (score 2):

This book you mention (https://leanpub.com/suitecrmfordevelopers) is worth investing in. It's the right stuff in one place.

SugarCRM resources and references are ok, however, SuiteCRM and SugarCRM are gradually going in different directions. If you rely on forums and generic blogs, even SOF, the 'Sugar' solution not always maps to a suite-solution. It can be close, but that last 5% of difference can be a headache to work through.

Anyhow, that's my plug/recommendation for that book.